# std::forward Visual Studio 13 doesn't behave like I expect

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to learn some basic C++ 11, using Scott Meyers lecture on youtube called "An Effective C++11/14 Sampler"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BezbcQIuCsY

Using his sample code for `std::forward`  (min 19 in the lecture) I wrote the following code to understand the effect of `std::forward`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class A
{
public:
    void Foo(std::string&& s)
    {
        std::string s2 = std::forward<std::string>(s);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    A a;

    std::string s3 = "Hello World";
    a.Foo(s3);
    a.Foo("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly it doesn't compile, `a.Foo(s3)` can't implicitly cast from lvalue to rvalue. So I changed `a.Foo(s3);` to `a.Foo(std::move(s3));` Now it compiles.
However on both calls to Foo `std::forward<std::string>(s);` resolved to an rvalue and a Move operation occurred (s was reset to `""` as its buffer was pilfered).

So I really don't understand what good is `std::forward` and when it does apply. What am I missing here?

Comment: `std::string&&` is an rvalue reference, not a forwarding reference (or "universal reference" as it was known for a while).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `std::forward<>` when template argument deduction / reference collapsing isn't involved doesn't make sense.

The point of *forwarding references* (which Scott Meyers used to call "universal references") is that, *depending on the value category of what you're receiving*, you can forward that value category as well.

But here, you're not confused at all as to what's the value category, it's static.

Here is a context that has template argument deduction:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& t) // T is to be deduced, && might be collapsed
{
  g(std::forward<T>(t)); // will keep the category value
}

f(std::string{"hey"}); // T inferred std::string&&, so the parameter type is `std::string&& &&`, which is collapsed to `std::string &&`.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a forwarding reference:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

class A
{

public:

    template <typename String>
    void Foo(String&& s)
    {
        std::string s2 = std::forward<String>(s);
    }
};



int main()
{
    A a;

    std::string s3 = "Hello World";
    a.Foo(s3);
    a.Foo("Hello World");

    return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/59e2db1e16dbcaf0)</kbd>